# Chroot SFTP user in Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, sftp, chroot, restricted-access

Good morning, I have a basic Ubuntu EC2 webserver with Apache, and several different websites on it. I log in to it via SSH with the access key provided by AWS to do basic stuff (I am a developer, not very much a sysadmin), and upload files via SFTP.

Now we need to allow one particular client to access one of the websites. I created a new linux user, enabled PasswordAuthentication in sshd_config, and made the website folder his home directory. But it can navigate through the server and access other folders as well, which I'd like to disallow.

I googled quite a bit, I followed this article among the others: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-restricting-ssh-user-session-to-a-directory-chrooted-jail/

But when I put the last lines in the sshd_config, it doesn't allow me to login with the restricted user anymore, so it isn't working.

There is some more-easy way to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new group and add the user to that group.

Set the user to login to its own HOME in /home/$USER/ (not to any dir outside the home) and then symlink the files and directories you want them to be able to edit.  Set the files in there to `chmod 700`

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` needs this:

```
Subsystem sftp {somename}
 
   Match Group {somegroup}
   ChrootDirectory /home
   ForceCommand {somename}
   X11Forwarding no
   AllowTcpForwarding no
```

and that user can not get outside of its /home and can only access the file available through the symlink.

If you want a different partition for this you can do that too but use a directory for that where you set it to `root:root` and in there use the username and groupname. A user will not be able to go outside the root directory (as it is owned by root). The above config can be used. `ChrootDirectory` then needs to be that directory you set to "root".